# force close when send data to webserver

Tags: android

i try send data to web server.

first. i use only `HttpResponse` to know the data is sent or not in device and it works

and i try to put `ResponseHandler` to know the data is sent or not read in webserver.

i create two response.

when the data is not sent or fail,
both of them, the error message and the toast is show and works

but when the data is sent the toast is show but the error message not show  and then force close

here is my code

```
private boolean SendDataFoto(CPetakRecord rec){


        String slon=String.format("%f", rec.dLongitude);
        String slat=String.format("%f", rec.dLatitude);
        String sacc=String.format("%f", rec.dAccuracy);
        String jnsHm=String.format(rec.jenisHm);
        String jmlHm=String.format(rec.jumlahHm);
        String jnsMsh=String.format(rec.jenisMsh);
        String jmlMsh=String.format(rec.jumlahMsh);
        String intens=String.format(rec.intensitas);
        String luasAncam=String.format(rec.luasTerancam);
        String nmPetak=String.format(rec.nmPetak);
        String code=String.format(rec.code);
        String userId=String.format(rec.userId);
        String varietas=String.format(rec.varietas);
        String dbLon=String.format("%f", rec.dbLon);
        String dbLat=String.format("%f", rec.dbLat);


        File file=new File(rec.sFilename);
        String sfname=file.getName();
        String cfname=file.getName();
        String lfname=rec.sFilename;
        sfname = sfname.substring(0, sfname.lastIndexOf("."));
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date(rec.lDate));
        String sdat=CUtilities.DateToString(cal);


        String url;
        String spetak;
        if (CGeneral.nPetakTetap==CGeneral.ACTIVITY_FOR_PETAK){
            url = CGlobalConfig.getURLRcvrPetak();
            spetak="petak";
        }
        else{
            url = CGlobalConfig.getURLRcvrPeliharaImage();
            spetak="pelihara";
        }

        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lfname);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

        HttpEntity entity=null;

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(ba, spetak+"_"+cfname);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
            reqEntity.addPart("category", new StringBody(spetak));
            reqEntity.addPart("foto", new StringBody(spetak+"_"+cfname));//
            reqEntity.addPart("tgl", new StringBody(sdat));//
            reqEntity.addPart("lat_petak", new StringBody(slat));//
            reqEntity.addPart("lon_petak", new StringBody(slon));//
            reqEntity.addPart("accuracy", new StringBody(sacc));
            reqEntity.addPart("jenis_hama", new StringBody(jnsHm));//
            reqEntity.addPart("jumlah_hama", new StringBody(jmlHm));//
            reqEntity.addPart("jenis_musuh", new StringBody(jnsMsh));//
            reqEntity.addPart("jumlah_musuh", new StringBody(jmlMsh));//
            reqEntity.addPart("int_serangan", new StringBody(intens));//
            reqEntity.addPart("luas_terancam", new StringBody(luasAncam));//
            reqEntity.addPart("nama_petak", new StringBody(nmPetak));//
            reqEntity.addPart("code_db", new StringBody(code));//
            reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(userId));//
            reqEntity.addPart("varietas", new StringBody(varietas));//
            reqEntity.addPart("lon_db", new StringBody(dbLon));//
            reqEntity.addPart("lat_db", new StringBody(dbLat));//

            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response2 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            //if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            final String reverseString = response2;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(UpdateLog.this, "response : " + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                });
            entity = response.getEntity();
            //}

        }

        catch (final ClientProtocolException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(UpdateLog.this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                });
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(UpdateLog.this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                });
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
        String temp = null;

        try {

            if(entity == null){
                publishProgress(0,"Send Fail");
                SystemClock.sleep(500);
                return false;
            }
            else{
            temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS") == 0) {
            publishProgress(0,"Send Ok");
            SystemClock.sleep(500);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            publishProgress(0,"Send Fail");
            return false;               
        }   

    }
```

and here is my logcat

```
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at hariff.ltis.petaktetap.UpdateLog$MyAsyncTaskPetak.SendDataFoto(UpdateLog.java:961)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at hariff.ltis.petaktetap.UpdateLog$MyAsyncTaskPetak.doInBackground(UpdateLog.java:814)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at hariff.ltis.petaktetap.UpdateLog$MyAsyncTaskPetak.doInBackground(UpdateLog.java:1)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
03-28 00:38:43.421: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3028):     ... 4 more
```

the error is in line `if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS") == 0) {`

how to fix that?,  i want the toast and the error message is show together when the data is sent.

Comment: Was temp initialized?

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
if(entity == null){
    publishProgress(0,"Send Fail");
    SystemClock.sleep(500);
    return false;
}
```

It appears an exception is thrown which prevents the code from running `return false`. The exception is caught, but `temp` is still not initialized. So you see the NullPointerException a few lines down.

You should see an orange stack trace from the initial error, address the error there and this NullPointerException will no longer be an issue.  (You might also want to add `return false;` to your catch-blocks.

Lastly I assume `SystemClock.sleep(500);` is the problem, blocking any thread is unnecessary, you should use a handler and Runnable to run code after a delay.